# Is there a legal minimum on the amount of soil needed to make a suitable grave?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave, outer-space

This is not being asked for any pragmatic need.  I had the thought about people living off of planets.

Without getting into the issue of whether a burial can take place anywhere beside Earth, I wonder; is there is a minimum of soil needed to be a suitable grave?

Justification for the question, on Earth, seems difficult. An area composed only of solid stone or some other impregnable stratum, perhaps. If you think the question is only ask-able off the Earth, raising other issues, I welcome that assumption be challenged.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there is *not.*  Common practice in the Temple era (and earlier) was to place bodies in caves and let the bodies decompose down to the bones, which were then collected and placed in the family tomb.  No actual burial was done.

However, I have not learned the relevant *halakhot,* so I'm not sure if what was done in that era is still halakhically normative.

Comment: Citing whatever source you have Like a gemara in bava basra or whatever would be helpful. And why you associate it with any specific time period.

Comment: @user6591 -  Not exactly what you're looking for, but sources are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beit_Guvrin_National_Park) and [here](http://old.parks.org.il/BuildaGate5/general2/data_card.php?Cat=~25~~131474600~Card12~&ru=&SiteName=parks&Clt=&Bur=466258966)

Comment: Nice. But i meant to put it into your answer. I was aware of this burial procedure from the gemara, but i don't recall if there was a time time period or not, that was my personal reason to ask.